# how to pass context from model and get in view in odoo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

How to pass context from the model and get in view in Odoo?

```
@api.onchange('partner_id')
def _onchange_customer(self):
    p_list = []
    for res in self.partner_id:
        res.product_list = self.env['res.partner'].search([('id', '=', self.partner_id.id)]).product_list_ids
        for rec in res.product_list:
            p_list.append(rec.id)
        print("11111111111111", p_list)
        return super(InvoiceProduct, self.env.context[tuple(p_list)])
```

View:

```
<field name="invoice_line_ids">
    <tree editable="bottom">
        <field name="product_id" required="True" context="{'product_list_id': context.get(p_list)}"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

Comment: Can you get into more detail about your requirement? Maybe there is another solution, because you can't change the context of a view with onchange methods. You can "only" fill fields, set domains on relational fields in the view and "raise" a warning message.

Comment: i have assign products to customers in contacts by custom field.i want that product list in invoicing also @CZoellner

Comment: Okay i try to describe that a bit more. So you have a list of products on customers (partners) which should be used in other business documents like invoices. In those other business documents this product list should be used to filter setable products, for example in invoice lines. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, exactly....